# What is that insect?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I was bitten by this insect (no big deal, but I cannot identify it). I took a picture of it (with my phone, so the picture is not great). I was sitting under some sort of vine tree (downtown though), and I think it fell from it. If that helps it happened in mid July 2016, in Montreal, Quebec, Canada.

I looked on several resources for biting insects in Montreal but I could not identify it. It was very small and yellow.

Also, the insect bit me, took some blood, and left me with a light burning sensation for about 10 mins. I am not a specialist at all in this, and I know nothing about insects, so I apologize for what I am going to write, but if I was to describe it, I'd say it was a weird mix between a very small yellow lizard (for the shape of the first half of the body) and a quite furry(for how it looked under). The head was shaped like a sharp triangle.

That's all the information I have, I hope that helps you identifying it!

[image]

Comment: Hmm, that's a difficult picture. How small would you say it was?

Comment: @picapica I would say it was around 1 cm long max, a few mm large max. This is actually the second one I saw. I killed the first one when I slapped my ankle (that's where I saw that it bled too much, and figured it took some from me)

Comment: I'm getting a leaf hopper feeling from the general shape of it. But I don't think those bite... Hope someone else can solve this mystery!

Comment: @picapica I checked leaf hopper, it looks a bit similar for under the body (I remember a few small "I don't know what" maybe small legs? hairs?), but the overall shape I am not sure. Thanks for the suggestion though. I met that bug twice at a coffee where I go on a regular basis, so next time I see it I'll do better pics! Meanwhile I'll keep looking on my own too!

Answer (score 5):

The shape looks like a leafhopper for sure. There are several species that are known to bite humans though it is not very common. Without a better photo however it may difficult to say what species it is for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll try to get a better picture when I see another one!

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you were bitten by a yellow Katydid. 
[image: Yellow Katydid]

According to Wikipedia,

> [Large tettigoniids can inflict a painful bite or pinch if handled, but
>   seldom break the skin.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tettigoniidae)

Comment: Thank you, it looks similar but what is under the body does not match what I have seen. I should have taken a pic of the insect upside down, but it looked "furry" under. Thanks for the idea though, I'll try to look at more pics to have a better idea!

Comment: The leg configuration doesn't seem to match to me.

Comment: Very unlikely. By "biting if handled",  it literally means if you stick your finger in its mouth. Katydids wouldn't attack/bite a person under any normal circumstance.

Comment: Large katydids sometimes bite defensively if you try to pick them up.  E.g., true katydid _Pterophylla camellifolia_, predatory ones like _Chlorobalius leucoviridis_.

Comment: No, not a katydid.